# NodeJS asynchronous.end() not working on POST request

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, http, request

I am trying to return text based on **database query** - for account registration - on the **$.ajax success'** parameter, after many search, I can't get what is wrong with the code below.

I can't find how to send http response that require asynchronous function, if I try to do it, the request is not handled or detected at all.

I think that the problem is that my that res.end("false") call is not called in time, but the code looks correct to me.

I don't want to use express and all callback are working correctly however I'm sure the problem is on **server.js** where I put comment

**client-side:**

```
$.ajax({
     async: true,
     dataType: "text",
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'http://192.168.0.23:3000',
     data: JSON.stringify(account_info),
     contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
     success: function (res) {
         console.log('Account registration : ' + res);
     },
     complete: function (res) {
            console.log('Account registration complete : ' +  
            JSON.stringify(res));
     },
    error: function (err) {
        console.log(err.responseText)
    }
});
```

**server-side:**

***server.js***

```
const http = require('http');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Visitor = require('./models/visitor.js');
var Account = require('./models/account.js');
var api = require('./controllers/api.js');
var isExisting = api.isExisting;
var saveData = api.saveData;
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer();
console.log('server is listening on ' + port);
server.listen(port);
server.on('request', function (request, response) {

    response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
    response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

    console.log(request.method);

    var body = '';

    request.on('data', function (data) {
        body += data;
    });

    request.on('end', function () {

        //In case there's content in the POST request
        if (body) {
            console.log('\nRequest content:' + body + '\n');
            body = JSON.parse(body);
            mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
            mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/someDB', {
                useMongoClient: true
            });

            //Pattern = ACCOUNT_REGISTRATION
            if (body.pattern == 'account_registration') {
                var value = {
                    email: body.email
                }
                var new_data = new Account(Account.store(body));
                //Check if account_name or website URL already in db
                // exist returning the callback
                isExisting(Account, value, function (exist) {
                    console.log(exist);
                    if (!exist) {
                        saveData(new_data);
                        //If you dont remove this line, the request is not detected by nodeJS
                        response.end('true');

                    } else {
                        console.log('\nAccount already exist.');
                        //If you dont remove this line, the request is not detected by nodeJS
                        response.end('false');
                        mongoose.connection.close();

                        }

                    });
                }
            }
            //Here it's working good but If I remove this line it'll not handle the request at all
            response.end('oko');
        });
    });
```

**api.js**

```
// The API controller
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

//Send some new_data to db
exports.saveData = function (new_data) {
    //Data saving into MongoDB database
    new_data.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        console.log('\nData successfully added.');
        // We need to disconnect now
        mongoose.connection.close();
    });
}

exports.isExisting = function (ModelName, value, callback) {
    ModelName.count(value, function (err, count) {
        if (err)
            throw err;
        if (count == 0)
            callback(false);
        else
            callback(true);
    });
}
```

**LAST EDIT:** In short,

This is what I get when I don't remove the last line (normal behavior but **I can't get my asynchronous response**

```
server is listening on 3000 
OPTIONS 
POST Request content:{"*****"}//real data already in db 
true //This is isExisting() callback
Account already exist.
```

But when I remove the last response.end('oko'), everything after OPTIONS not appear...

Comment: `if (!exist) { saveData(new_data); }` Where do you send the response when there's not an existing account? Not in saveData(). I assume it gets sent by the `response.end( 'oko' )` line you want to remove, so have you tried `if (!exist) { saveData(new_data); response.end( 'oko' ); }`

Comment: I guess your edit explains it.

Comment: If I remove response.end( 'oko' ); the request is not handled anymore, however, with the above code, all the response.end calls I made near isExist() are not executed, even if I remove the last one...

Comment: Have you found where it stops? Do you still see the `console.log(exist);` DO you still have a body that has a pattern account_registration? Have you tried wrapping everything into a try/catch to check for errors? Sorry for the questions, but don't have mongo or mongoose on this machine, so can't test it myself to see where it stops.

Comment: It stops before one of the first line of server.js                                                     console.log(request.method);  In normal execution I got OPTIONS and POST in log, but I got only OPTIONS if I remove the last response, it's like the other calls are not send in time...

Comment: This is what I get when I let the last line `server is listening on 3000
    OPTIONS
    POST

    Request content:{"*****"}//real data here

    true

    Account already exist.` But when I remove the last response.end('oko'), everything after OPTIONS not appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand the issue now.

You're making a CORS request. And all CORS requests send an OPTIONS request first to the server before sending the actual request to check if the Access Control headers actually allow the request to be handled by the server.

Since your request handler checks for the existance of a body.pattern, which won't exists for a OPTIONS request, the response is never sent.

So the request never gets responded to and your POST request never reaches the server because it doesn't get permission to do so from the OPTIONS request.

So if you add something like `if ( method === 'OPTIONS' ) { response.end() } else if ( body ) { ... }` you'll assure that the options will get handled.

To be safe make sure that all requests get answered, even if you just answer with an error or a 404.

Comment: This is the answer I needed, wow thanks really it works now can't believe it was actually so simple, but can you explain me why 'synchronous' response (like the last line of server.js) was succesfully sent back without handling OPTIONS request ?

Comment: Because you manually create the body with `var body = '';` and have the `on( 'data' )` add things to it ( which aren't a property pattern ) so that it will satisfy the `if ( body )` check, but not the `if (body.pattern )` check. SO the OPTIONS request would go into the `if body` part, and then would get ended by `response.end('oko');`. When you then remove that `response.end('oko');`, the response is not sent. If instead of constructing the body yourself, you would try to directly use the body from the POST request, you'd get an error sooner since the OPTIONS would not satistfy `if ( body )`

Comment: Since most type of requests OPTIONS, GET, POST etc will get handled different, I usually wrap all specific functionality inside a method check. SO I would only define a body and add data to it, fi the request was a POST request.

Comment: I was sure it has something to do with the placement of response.end() like I had to put another callback somewhere but I just forgot to handle the OPTIONS request, thanks a million time, I'd never figured out myself !